# How to harden Google Cloud VM running RStudio Server on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, security, google-cloud-platform, rstudio

I am running RStudio Server on a VM on GCP. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.4.1087-5/hardening.html) and used the example configuration with as many of the options as would work for the open-source edition.

(Well other than an SSL certificate. I'm accessing through an external IP, not domain name. So I can't generate a google managed certificate or one through any of the free services.)

Hopefully, this handles the RStudio Server aspects.

However, I should also take measures due to ports 80 and 443 being open as well, right?

Will the standard GCP firewall take care of most of that, or is there more I should do?

AFAICT, RStudio Server is running its own web server--there doesn't seem to be any `apache` or `nginx` or anything running.

```
(base) balter@rstudio:/etc$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  chrony
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  iscsid
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  multipath-tools
 [ - ]  open-iscsi
 [ - ]  open-vm-tools
 [ + ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: Have you tried using the GCP firewall? This seems like something you can easily check yourself.

Comment: @music2myear I pretty much kept the default GCP firewall settings.

Comment: Then do you actually have a question? Do you KNOW you have a problem, or do you THINK you MIGHT have a problem? Please edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I believe it's always good to be proactive about hardening a server. I could wait until my server becomes a world-wide nexus for viagra spam or porn. But I'd rather know my server is hard than have it become a way for other people to get hard.

Comment: But you need a specific and known issue in order to get a specific and correct answer. Open ended discussion questions are not bad. I am not saying that. But this site is about clear questions that can have a single specific and correct answer. Open discussion like "how do I harden given system against known and unknown attacks?" are better asked in a forum where open discussion is the point of the site.

Comment: @music2myearI I respectfully disagree. If I google "harden ubuntu server" it's quite easy to find 10^6 guides with steps to harden a server. These tell you what steps to avoid to protect against different types of attacks. They do not assume you have a _specific_ thing you are hardening against. It seems totally reasonable to describe the type of server I have, list the firewalls I've enabled, and ask if there are any other major vulnerabilities I should be aware of.